# Mechanism to even out force from linear motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, mechanisms, building-physics

Not sure exactly how to explain this, but I am looking to use a threaded rod connected to a motor, to push and pull open a gate valve. My idea for this is to attach a nut to the handle of the pull/push rod of the valve, and have this run through a fixed threaded rod. Turning the motor, spins the threaded rod, moving the nut up and down the shaft, which the pull handle is connected to.

With that being said, I am thinking that having the nut on one side of the pull handle will lead to angular pressure, as the nut is not centered on the handle.

One way around this, would be to add another motor on the other side, to push the handle down at either end.

My question is, is there another way? Is there some type of mechanism i can make/print, in order to even out the pressure on both sides, while only having one motor/screw combo.

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the specific mechanical setup since things like slop and rigidity come into play. It might not even be a problem. Lots of things have forced applied unevenly and work just fine while many others do not.

Comment: Once the threaded rod is inline with the gate valve handle how do you expect it to start to open it?

Comment: The motor drives the threaded rod. similar to how an X/Y axis would work on a cnc/3d printer.

Comment: have the threaded rod be the part that moves and rotate the nut.  You're replacing a normal handwheel with an automated version.

Comment: what kind of a handle is on the gate valve? ... how many turns from open to close?

Comment: your post is an XY question ... it asks about your solution to a problem, instead of asking about the problem